# Easiest Jquery/Javascript hover window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, dhtml

I'm looking for the easiest solution, preferably integrated with Jquery, for opening a div / url in a hover window (javascript window). Any suggestions?

Comment: what the heck is a `hover window`?

Comment: OP is probably referring to a modal window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) pretty easy, specifically the [`Dialog` widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

HTML:

```
<div id="myDialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog.
       The dialog window can be moved, resized and
       closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript (once the DOM is loaded):

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({autoOpen: false});
```

Then to open it:

```
$("#myDialog").dialog('open');
```

It has its own close button, or you can close it:

```
$("#myDialog").dialog('close');
```